# What can I do to speed up deb pkg building with dh-virtualenv?

Tags: python, deb

I am looking for techniques to speed up building a deb pkg from my python application:

```
Source: my-shiny-app
Section: python
Priority: extra
Maintainer: me <me_write_me@me.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), python, dh-virtualenv (>= 0.6-1)
Standards-Version: 3.9.5

Package: my-shiny-app
Architecture: amd64
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1), python2.7, ${misc:Pre-Depends}
Depends: ${python:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, libzmq1
Description: my-app
```

The most of the time takes building python libraries that my application depends on.

UPDATE:

I have found [a ticket in dh-virtualenv github](https://github.com/spotify/dh-virtualenv/issues/94). They suggest to use pip7. Pip7 supports local caching of wheel packages (copy&paste from the ticket):

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --with python-virtualenv


WHEEL_ROOT:=    file:///var/wheelhouse

override_dh_virtualenv:
    pip wheel -w=$(WHEEL_ROOT) -f $(WHEEL_ROOT) -r requirements.txt
    dh_virtualenv \
        --extra-pip-arg "--use-wheel" \
        --extra-pip-arg "--find-links=$(WHEEL_ROOT)"
```

Problem is: the created deb package does not include python and libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If building dependencies is the bottleneck, try upgrading to the latest version of pip. The later versions store pre-built packages in a local wheel cache making subsequent builds much faster.

If downloading packages takes long, you should [copy your dependencies to a local folder on your build-server](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages). Make sure you copy the packages to local folder on the file system. While pip supports access via `--find-links=http://your-local-package-host/`, collecting dependencies is still rather slow unless you set up https & proper caching headers for the package host.

If installing the app itself is taking long (hangs after "Processing /some/folder") then you're experiencing the [slow copy pip installation issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2195). You could try to work around that by replacing `pip install .` with `python setup.py sdist` and `pip install dist/my-shiny-app-1.0.tar.gz` in dh-virtualenv.

Comment: Enforcing the installation of the newest pip sped things a little bit (debian/rules):
override_dh_virtualenv:
 dh_virtualenv --preinstall='pip>7'